# DataTables Laravel 5.4 Undefined Index with Ajax Request

Tags: datatables, laravel-5.4

I use **DataTables** and **yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle** package for **Laravel 5.4**. I want display **screen_name** in column **screen_name**. **screen_name** is in JSON object (*JSON result*).

## Ajax script code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#logs-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        stateSave: true,
        ajax: 'api/ajax-file',
        columns: [
            { data: 'credentials.screen_name', name: 'credentials.screen_name' }
        ],
        aoColumns: [
            {
                aTargets: [0],
                mData: 'credentials.screen_name',
                mRender: function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<strong>' + data + '</strong>';
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

## HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="logs-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

## JSON result:

```
{
    "draw":0,
    "recordsTotal":208,
    "recordsFiltered":208,
    "data": [{
        "_id":"5960e2f59f9d5158f7129d82",
        "credentials":{
            "id":"1",
            "id_str":"1",
            "name":"User 1",
            "screen_name":"user1"
        },
        ...
    }]
}
```

## Yajra Query:

```
public function ajax(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::all();
    return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
}
```

## I have this error:

[image]

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure to have a `credentials.screen_name` for all your 208 results? Because it will throw the same error otherwise.

Comment: I have take only one line, I haven't this error, but I have one result. If I take 2 lines or more, I have this error... I understand...

Comment: public function ajax(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::take(1)->get();
    return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
}

Comment: What happens if you replace `$users = User::all();` by `$users = User::has('credentials.screen_name')->get();`?

Comment: I use method Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder for that. I can't use has() method...